# Render settings for large scene - fixing render time

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I'm not sure about proper settings for my scene (cycles render). I want to balance time of the rendering and the realism, because render takes very long time (f.e. because of used textures, with every modificatior on - like subdivisions etc - there is 560k verts so in my opinion it isn't that much). I am using the pro lighting skies addon for lighting - "morning03" and "cloudy08". In the first version I used glossy shader imitating water, and on the second I added leaves (objects copied with the help of the particle system and weight paint). These are results my previous renders (scenes differ a bit from themselves - one version is priorer and other one is more detailed). Some scenes don't look *that* bad, but their render time for sure is.

Morning: 
Default settings with little modifications:
[image]
Other settings (much lower - render time drop to 3h)

[image]
[image]

Cloudy: 
Default settings with little modifications (render time 3-7h)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked removing or lowering the resolution of the textures of each leaf in the scene? Just to see how much does this speeds up your render. Also, are you using sub surface scattering for the leaves? That can greatly increase any render time. Great scene by the way.

Comment: Leaves are created from plane with one subdivision, rest  of the shape is received by shaders  (bump etc).
model: http://iv.pl/images/73558740013624588823.jpg
result: http://iv.pl/images/29896247796253811564.jpg One leaf texture is 632KB size. As regards materials a surface texture is a biggest problem, I received it through texture painting and to keep details of the brush I had to create the very big plain (13000x13000...). Unfortunately I didn't find other remedy how to do it in cycles, only in Game render there is a simpler way...